# Solr 1.3 ignore word "jackie"

Tags: search, lucene, solr, analyzer

I  am using Solr 1.3. Recently, QA report a bug for the search functionality that there is no result for the word "Jackie". But, when i looked into document using luke, there is lots of document with the word "jackie" e.g.

```
 Jackie Holding, Kumar Rameshwaram, Morris Jackson
 Jackie Holding, Brendon Wessel, Smith McShlam
 Jackie Redmond, John Smith, Martha Doum
 Trevor Harris, Jackie Collins, Martin Green
```

If i search for any term other than jackie, solr return the documents.But no documents for the word "Jackie". Even, i try it with all analyzer, solr return no document.

I am not able to figure out the problem. Please help me.

Comment: please post the entire fieldType declaration.

Comment: @Mauricio: url of doc field type http://pastebin.com/QjZnDTQb

Comment: that's not a fieldType. see http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml

Comment: @Mauricio:Sorry, this is the url for schema.xml http://pastebin.com/cJr8iBeV

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple of ideas:

- try setting `debugQuery=on` when querying Jackie in the Solr admin console. See how it gets analyzed.
- Check that 'Jackie' is not in the stopwords list (stopwords.txt)
- Try adding 'Jackie' to the protected word list (protwords.txt) so it doesn't get stemmed.

Comment: Thank you very much. It works by adding the word 'Jackie' in protwords.txt

Answer (score 1):

Verify that, in your schema, the filter factories for your query and index analyzers are corresponding (they should have the same stemming configuration, for instance). Of course, if you have changed your schema since indexing, then the query analyzer filters should match the ones that were used at index time, or you will have to re-index.

The problem you describe typically occurs when the query analyzer uses a different stemming configuration than the index analyzer (for instance using different languages).